Is there a process by which we can simplify the limit definition of the derivative for any differentiable function into something usable?
When finding the derivative of a specific function using the limit definition (i. e. $f’(x) = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$, generally I’ve used a lot of tricks.
With polynomials, the $h$s cancel out perfectly. With fractional and negative powers, I can use their binomial expansion and other tricks.
With $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, I can use their Maclaurin series.
With $e^x$, I use a way of defining $e$ in terms of the limit of $n$ as it tends to infinity of $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$.
I did something similar for $\cosh(x)$, $\sinh(x)$, etc. I derived the product and chain rules. From this, I could find the derivatives of inverses.
It feels like I used a bunch of tricks to find the derivative of different simple functions.
Does a process exist (for a differentiable function) to simplify the limit definition into something usable?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What do you even mean by "something usable"? You've clearly been able to already use the definition for most of the basic functions one encounters. Since functions can be defined in basically any way one likes, you can't really expect something "better", and I'd say we're honestly quite lucky to even get the derivatives of most of the functions we care about so easily, as the same is very far from true for integrals

It's not really clear what you want. The derivative rules (product rule, chain rule etc.) give you an algorithm once you have the derivatives of a few basic functions down. What else are you looking for?

The general process is part of "calculus" and is given in the textbooks. Likely you already know the process.

Concerning $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ the application of the MacLaurin series is a circular argument. You need to know the derivatives of these functions for deriving their MacLaurin series.
